# Executable Jar: JMSCC0091: The provider factory for connection type 'com.ibm.msg.client.wmq' could not be loaded

Tags: ibm-mq, spring-jms, jmstemplate, uberjar

I encountered this very weird problem while working on using JMSTemplate to connect to IBM Websphere MQ. The code runs perfectly fine in Eclipse, but when I use shade plugin to package the project and all the dependencies into an Uber jar, I got this error while executing the jar file:

```
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSCC0091: The provider factory for  connection type 'com.ibm.msg.client.wmq' could not be loaded.
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor4.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:437)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:319)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.nls.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:233)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsErrorUtils.createException(JmsErrorUtils.java:109)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsFactoryFactoryImpl.getInstance(JmsFactoryFactoryImpl.java:172)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.setProviderFactory(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:167)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:254)
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createCommonConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6215)
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:120)
```

Here is my relevant Java code to read the keystore and truststore file as InputStream and the error happened when the method **createQueueConnection** was called.

```
InputStream keystoreInput = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(keystoreFile);
InputStream truststoreInput = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(trustStoreFile);
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
char[] keyPassword = keystorePassword.toCharArray();
keyStore.load(keystoreInput, keyPassword);

KeyManagerFactory keyFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
keyFactory.init(keyStore, keyPassword);

KeyManager[] keyManagers = keyFactory.getKeyManagers();
KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

char[] trustPassword = trustStorePassword.toCharArray();
trustStore.load(truststoreInput, trustPassword);

TrustManagerFactory trustFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
trustFactory.init(trustStore);

TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustFactory.getTrustManagers();
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
sslContext.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, null);
SSLContext.setDefault(sslContext);

MQQueueConnectionFactory cf = ctx.getBean("mqIdsConnectionFactory", MQQueueConnectionFactory.class);
cf.setSSLSocketFactory((SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault());
MQQueueConnection connection = (MQQueueConnection) cf.createQueueConnection();
```

I checked my xml file and all the IBM MQ dependencies are included correctly, and I can find the class files in the uber jar as well. It has been bothering me in the past few days and if anybody knows how to fix it, I would really appreciate your input and suggestions.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.ibm.mq</artifactId>
    <version>7.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.ibm.mqjms</artifactId>
    <version>7.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.headers</artifactId>
    <version>7.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.jmqi</artifactId>
    <version>7.5.0</version>
</dependency>        
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
    <artifactId>dhbcore</artifactId>
    <version>7.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.jsse2</groupId>
    <artifactId>ibmjsseprovider2</artifactId>
    <version>7.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>ibmjcefw</artifactId>
    <version>7.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.crypto</groupId>
    <artifactId>ibmjceprovider</artifactId>
    <version>7.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>ibmcertpathprovider</artifactId>
    <version>7.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>ibmpkcs</artifactId>
    <version>7.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
    <artifactId>connector</artifactId>
    <version>7.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: If you review IBM MQ 7.5 Knowledge Center page "[What is installed for IBM WebSphere MQ classes for JMS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031540_.htm)" it states the following "**Do not include the IBM WebSphere MQ classes for JMS JAR files within application archives (such as enterprise application archives, or EAR files).**", so it would appear that bundling the IBM MQ jar files into a Uber jar with the shade is not supported by IBM.

Comment: @JoshMc, your answer is very close, the culprit is indeed the shade plugin, but the reason is that shade plugin would extract the class files from the dependency jar files and package them in the uber jar, which may cause class name collision to cause the error. I switched to SpringBoot to build the uber jar, which would contain all the dependency jars and is about 50% bigger in size, and it finally works!

Comment: While it may be technically possible to do what you are doing, IBM says that it should not be done, in that case it may be flagged as an issue if you tried to get support from IBM on a problem, if you want to be sure you have a supported configuration you could open a PMR with IBM and ask them that question.

Comment: Do you have the MQ Client installation on that machine ?

Comment: Yes, I do have MQ client installation on that machine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to not extract the dependencies inside the jar but just include them as stated in the comments.  If you export from within eclipse, there is a radio option to choose from.