# Error while kafka connect with mq source- JMSCC0091: The provider factory for connection type 'com.ibm.msg.client.wmq' could not be loaded

Tags: apache-kafka, ibm-mq, apache-kafka-connect

We are using [kafka-connect-mqsource](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/kafka-connect-mq-source/blob/master/README.md#running-the-connector)
is a connector for copying data from IBM MQ into Apache Kafka.

we currently are using MQ version 7.5.0.8 but I can see from [readme](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/kafka-connect-mq-source/blob/master/README.md#running-the-connector) that it only support down to IBM MQ v8.0 or later.

if we use this code base we facing some exception as given

```
{"name":"kafka-mq-connector", "connector":{"state":"RUNNING", "worker_id":"192.888.002.05:7070"}, "tasks":[{"state":"FAILED","trace":"org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException:com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSCC0091: The provider factory for connection type 'com.ibm.msg.client.wmq' could not be loaded.\n\t
at com.mqkafka.kafkaconnector.MQReader.configure(MQReader.java:122).\n\t
at com.mqkafka.kafkaconnector.MQSourceTask.start(MQSourceTask.java:36).\n\t
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execut(WorkerSourceTask.java:157).\n\t
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:170).\n\t
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:214).\n\t
at
```

I am not sure whether its compatibility issue or some other issue. Can you please help with the fixes required to make this connector work, thanks in advance.

Comment: kafka-connect-mqsource connects as a client to the MQ queue manager, this means you do not need to use IBM MQ Classes for JMS (or Java) jar files that are from the same version as the queue manager.  A higher or lower version client can connect to a higher or lower version queue manager.  Unless the kafka-connect-mqsource is using a feature of v8 that is only available on a v8 queue manager the higher version client should work fine.  I would suggest that you go look for IBM MQ 9.0.0.2 Java-All Client, this will include the jars files you will need.

Comment: Thanks here is the [pom.xml](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/kafka-connect-mq-source/blob/master/pom.xml) file which I am using, it already has IBM MQ 9.0.4.0 Java-All Client. am I missing anything other than this?

Comment: Is that pom.xml file obtaining the com.ibm.allclient.jar automatically?  If so is it possible your classpath has jar files from other versions of MQ included as well, it would not work well with a mixture of different MQ versions' jar files.

Comment: Yes, it will obtain com.ibm.allclient.jar automatically while building uber/ fat jar using eclipse. What would be the approach to fix this issue, to make it work for version7.5.0.8 ibm Mq

Comment: Looks related to this "[Executable Jar: JMSCC0091: The provider factory for connection type 'com.ibm.msg.client.wmq' could not be loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47794927/executable-jar-jmscc0091-the-provider-factory-for-connection-type-com-ibm-msg)".  In that case the person asking the question stated they switched from shade to using SpringBoot to create the uber jar and it worked.  I pointed out that IBM documents that a uber jar is not a supported configuration.